# 5 steps answer is 3 digits plus decimal

Tags: cipher, visual

[image]

3 digits plus decimals 
takes 5 steps
has something to do with hex code as first step
you only need a calculator and smarts

Answer (score 2):

First step:

> Replacing the colors in the image with their hex values given by the legend (black = 0, grey = 1, red = 2, ... white = F) yields:
>
> ```
>  0C600634C402E26DBEA765C547C8B1
>  D9B906039CA5927D490D9C444D0471
>  A8632BB589B63C320F10E87E0C9D64
>  6123A5C0DF9DBA8C58853898A1E390
>  B3FD938C253BA155C5D24C
> ```

Comment: please explain your approach to this answer. thanks and happy puzzling ;)

Comment: Nice, keep going. The bars at the top have no order.